# how to access derived class methods from another derived class

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using wxpython to generate a GUI. The structure of the program I'm doing is shown below. I have a class for each section of the GUI (class1 and class2). I'm using the Panel class to create these sections. class1 and class2 are derived from another class (the Group class). I want to access the methods of a derived class from the other derived class on the fly. So when I'm in classA.method1() I want to call classB.method3(). what is the best way to do that?

```
class Panel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        class1 = ClassA()
        class2 = ClassB()


class Group(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        .
        .
        .


class ClassA(Group):

    def method1(self):
        ....

    def method2(self):
        ....

class ClassB(Group):

    def method3(self):
        ....

    def method4(self):
        ....
```

Comment: `Group` has a constructor with parameters, but you use default constructors for `ClassA` and `ClassB`. Did you override the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I's assuming you want to call the class method, not the method of an instance of that class.

From ClassA.method1(), ClassB be should be a global, so all you have to do is:

```
class ClassA(Group):

    def method1(self):
        classB.method3(someclass)
```

Now all you have to do is figure out what you want to put in for 'someclass'.  If method3 never uses 'self' then just pass it None.  If ClassA is compatible, then you can pass it 'self'.  Otherwise, you need to pass it an instance of ClassB.

Comment: Actually I think I'm wrong, I think 'someclass' NEEDs to be an instance of ClassB.